# Display Latest Magento products without setting date

Tags: magento-1.7

I use Magento 1.7.0.2.

I'd like to show the 8 latest added products in my homepage, but without setting a date "from" and "to". I need it to be automatically.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product IDs are incremental. By ordering them descending and limiting the collection to 8 you will have 8 last products.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order('entity_id desc')->limit(8);

/* just for testing
Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->assemble());

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    Mage::log($product->getSku());
} */
```

With the collection you can do whatever you need, add visibility and status filter etc.

Comment: I need to diaplay all details of that latest products. What the Way? like price, image....

Answer (score 0):

in order to do that you will need to use the date that the order was created. The key to display all products information as price, name, and etc. is to us       `->addAttributeToSelect('*')` Here is the script:

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
  ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)  
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                          
  ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
  ->setPage(1, 9);
```